# Can't download Docker and containers on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, containers

Im new to docker and windows containers. Deploying on-premise solution on windows server 2016
go through this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server#prerequisites) and stuck on **Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force**

WARNING: Cannot find path
'C:\Users\ADM_AG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json' because it does not
exist.
WARNING: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'downloadURL' because it is an empty string.
WARNING: The property 'AbsoluteUri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: The property 'RequestMessage' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Docker'. Try Get-PackageSour
to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1

- Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], E
  ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
  ```

BUT somehow i've installed Docker

**get-service docker**

Status   Name               DisplayName

---

Stopped  docker             Docker Engine

**start-service docker**
start-service : Failed to start service 'Docker Engine (docker)'.
At line:1 char:1

- start-service docker
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
  ```

**docker version**
Client:
Version:      1.12.0-dev
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.5.3
Git commit:   8e92415
Built:        Thu May 26 17:08:34 2016
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

and now I can't download containers and launch Docker

**docker images**
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

**docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809**
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=mcr.microsoft.com%2Fwindows%2Fnanoserver&tag=1809: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot fin
d the file specified.

Containers in WindowsFeauture are enabled, TLS 1.2 is enabled, execution policy is not restricted

may it something related what dockerdefault and container image gallery are not trusted? if yes, how to set it are Trusted?

**get-packagesource**

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location

---

test                             NuGet            False      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    True       https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
ContainerImageGallery            ContainerImage   False      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746630&clcid=0x409
DockerDefault                    DockerMsftPro... False      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825636&clcid=0x409

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I would suggest you start over and first make sure the Containers feature is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would:

1. Start over by removing docker with:

   Option 1 method:

   ```
   docker ps --quiet | ForEach-Object {docker stop $_}
   docker system prune --volumes --all
   Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
   Uninstall-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider
   Get-HNSNetwork | Remove-HNSNetwork
   Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Docker" -Recurse
   ```

   Option 2, the brute force method:

   ```
   Stop-Service docker
   dockerd --unregister-service
   Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Docker" -Recurse
   Remove-Item "C:\Program Files\Docker" -Recurse
   ```

And reboot to a clean system.

2. Install the Docker Engine from scratch:

   ```
   # Install Containers feature
   Install-WindowsFeature Containers

   # RESTART THE SERVER!!!

   # Install Docker Module
   Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force

   # Install Docker
   Install-Package -Name Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force -Confirm:$false

   # Start Docker Engine
   Start-Service Docker
   ```

You should now have a working Docker installation.

3. Test the docker engine with the commands:

   ```
   docker version
   docker info
   ```

If you are still having issues executing the test commands above:

1. Make sure your Windows Firewall is turned off to make sure there is nothing in the way.
2. Also, make sure the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" is stopped just in case (at least for now).
3. Update the "PowerShellGet" module with

```
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.5 -Force
```

Let me know if it finally works.

FYI:
Container tags with "1809" are for Windows 2019.  So:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 ==> Windows 2019
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:sac2016 ==> Windows 2016
```

Important: The Windows container must match the Windows host that it will be running on.